# How can I choose the location where I want to save downloaded files?

Tags: javascript, html, grails, groovy

I have a Grail application under Groovy.  I export an Excel file.  I can export a file if I mention the file location in the code, but I want to keep the user choose file location on his PC.  What is HTML or JavaScript to do this?  Do you have any code to help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename= book.csv" );
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");  
response.outputStream << test.writeToString();
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot preselect anything. It always uses the browser default or the last used location. For example, in Firefox you can configure it in `Tools -> Options -> General -> Downloads`.

If a website could specify a default it would be easy to trick users into overwriting important files (by selecting a folder where a certain file is supposed to be and choosing the same filename and then hoping the user clicking yes in the "overwrite file?" dialog).