# how can i use the root directory System.getProperty("user.home")

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I use this method [`System.getProperty("user.home")`] in my grails application under groovy, to get the root directory and save a file in this directory, but when I deploy the website to the server and try this method the file saved in the server side not in the client one. It means that `System.getProperty("user.home")` get the root directory of the server not of the client. What can I do to get the client root directory and not the server one.

Comment: `System.properties['user.home]` is a Groovier way to get the property value, though I think you have much bigger problems to deal with. I don't wish to be rude, but this question demonstrates a poor understanding of the fundamentals of web development.

Comment: And creating secondary accounts to re-ask questions that you ignored the answer to before isn't going to make you many friends :-(

Answer (score 9):

You can't get the client's home directory.  And you cannot automatically save files onto a remote clients machine in the folder of your choice.

When you are running it on your own computer and calling `System.getProperty("user.home")` seems to work, it is only because you are browsing the site from the server as a local client.

As has been explained to you before in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835845/how-can-i-choose-the-location-where-i-want-to-save-downloaded-files), you cannot automatically save a file to a location chosen by you on the client's machine.

Not without installing some sort of client software on their machine anyway, or by using a signed applet or similar signed technology.

This would be a huge security issue otherwise.